# List regular files only (without directory) problem

Tags: c, posix, directory, readdir, stat

Do you know why certain files are not listed by this program, even if they are "regular"?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void) {
  DIR *dh = opendir("./"); // directory handle
  struct dirent *file; // a 'directory entity' AKA file    
  struct stat info; // info about the file.
  while (file = readdir(dh)) {
    stat(file->d_name, &info);
    printf("note: file->d_name => %s\n", file->d_name);
    printf("note: info.st_mode => %i\n", info.st_mode);
    if (S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
      printf("REGULAR FILE FOUND! %s\n", file->d_name);
  }
  closedir(dh);

  return 0;
}
```

After executed this program, I get this:

```
note: file->d_name => .
note: info.st_mode => 16877
note: file->d_name => ..
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => .DS_Store
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => ef efeff
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => ffffff
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => ffffff - copie
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => folder
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => printiie.tt
note: info.st_mode => 16832
note: file->d_name => test.c
note: info.st_mode => 33188
REGULAR FILE FOUND! test.c
note: file->d_name => z
note: info.st_mode => 33188
REGULAR FILE FOUND! z
```

As you can see, the program see's only two files. But every file is regular, and there is only one folder.

Here is a copy past of the shell command: `$ ls -lai` :

```
total 64
2421444 drwxr-xr-x  10 denis  staff   340 27 oct 22:19 .
2416789 drwxr-xr-x@ 28 denis  staff   952 27 oct 22:20 ..
2423204 -rw-r--r--@  1 denis  staff  6148 27 oct 21:41 .DS_Store
2423206 -rwxr-xr-x@  1 denis  staff   895 27 oct 19:57 ef efeff
2423183 -rwxr-xr-x@  1 denis  staff   895 27 oct 19:57 ffffff
2423216 -rwxr-xr-x@  1 denis  staff   895 27 oct 19:57 ffffff - copie
2423436 drwxr-xr-x   2 denis  staff    68 27 oct 21:57 folder
2423180 -rw-r--r--@  1 denis  staff    38 27 oct 21:32 printiie.tt
2423682 -rw-r--r--@  1 denis  staff   895 27 oct 19:57 test.c
2423208 -rwxr-xr-x@  1 denis  staff    34 27 oct 21:39 z
```

I would just like to list the name of each file, but without directories. I work on Mac OS X, but I don't think this could be the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `stat` function is failing for some of the files, so the `info` struct isn't being updated and still has the data in it from `".."`.  Replace that line with:

```
if (stat(file->d_name, &info))
{
    printf("error: stat(%s): %s\n", file->d_name, strerror(errno));
    continue;
}
```

..and you'll see why.

Comment: Thanks! I get this message for unlisted files: 
error: stat(printiie.tt): No such file or directory 

For the moment I don't understand why, because those files exist...

Comment: It looks to me like the directory you're examining with `opendir` isn't the same as the current working directory that `stat` is looking at.  What happens with `opendir(".")` instead?

Comment: after some tests, I get this: note: file->d_name => .
note: info.st_mode => 16877
note: file->d_name => ..
note: info.st_mode => 16832

It is strange because after deleting .DS_Store, the program detect 0 file.

Comment: `stat` returns 0 on success, -1 on failure, so the accepted code block is incorrect.  http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat

Comment: @somekindarukus: The body of the `if` statement here is supposed to execute when `stat()` *fails* - it is showing what the error was, then skipping to the next iteration of the loop.  The code is correct.

Answer (score -2):

I once had to list every yml file in directory including subdirectories. It was on Win XP:
`system("dir C:\Path\To\File\*.yml /B /S >> list.txt");` and then I would parse list.txt to get all of the them. One line was one file. Easy, but not portable. Also that was some time ago - now I would maybe try boost.

EDIT:
This answer is not about the code, but:

> Actually I just would like to list the name of each file, but without directories.

If he took the same approach as me, he would have his problem solved.