# How to print only files from a directory passed by command line argument

Tags: c, unix, stat, opendir

I have this code which outputs names of files and directories in current directory, how can I make it print **only files** from a specified directory

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <dirent.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <errno.h>

 int main (int c, char *v[]) {
     DIR * d;
     char * dir_name = ".";

     /* Open the current directory. */     
     d = opendir (dir_name);

     if (! d) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
                  dir_name, strerror (errno));
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     while (1) {
         struct dirent * entry;             
         entry = readdir (d);
         if (! entry) {
             break;
         }
         printf ("%s\n", entry->d_name);
     }
     /* Close the directory. */
     if (closedir (d)) {
         fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
                  dir_name, strerror (errno));
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     return 0; 
}
```

I have changed

```
 d = opendir (dir_name)
```

to

```
  d = opendir (v[1])
```

It opens a directory I need but it does not print only files, it prints everything what is in that directory.

Comment: Use `stat` to find which directory entries are regular files. See [List regular files only (without directory) problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633797/list-regular-files-only-without-directory-problem)

Comment: I think your current directory has only files. That's the reason you are getting only files. I mean no issue with opendir() as you seem to be claiming

Comment: Yes. Just noticed, anyway how could I achieve what I want?

Comment: @wooden, as Klas suggested try out stat.